# In a Parallel Radioactive decay , what is the ratio of sum of stable nuclei of the two products?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation

Here is the full Question

[image]

The question gives you two Rate constants and asks for what time will the ratio of "sum of stable nuclei of Ca:Ar" be equal to 99.But what is this ?If i think of number of nuclei in terms of concentration then the ratio of them is coming to be simply $$ \frac{k_1}{k_2}$$ and its value is already fixed , so either there must be an error in my working or there must be different understanding of "sum of stable nuclei of Ca:Ar"

[Here is my attempt at doing this from start](https://www.notion.so/In-a-radioactive-sample-40-_-19-K-nuclei-either-decay-into-stable-40-_-20-Ca-nuclei-with-deca-9100ed5d93cd4cbc9ee383fa34256157)

[Here is my notes on Parallel Reaction](https://www.notion.so/Parallel-Reactions-7b508ec084044c3db087595f6ba0f70a)

Answer (score 1):

You're misreading the problem.

Let the numbers of potassium, calcium, argon nuclei be $N_\text{K}$, $N_\text{Ca}$, $N_\text{Ar}$, all of which are functions of time.

You are correct that the ratio

$$\frac{N_\text{Ca}}{N_\text{Ar}}$$

is independent of time. But the question is about the ratio

$$\frac{N_\text{Ca}+N_\text{Ar}}{N_\text{K}}$$

which increases as the potassium decays away.